# Python - RPG name maker using lists

Tags: python

I am trying to make a 3 part name generator in python for an RPG game. I have a 2 dimensional array in order to combine 3 parts of a name:

```
name = [["Raan","Feim","Od","Yol","Dur"]["Mir","Zii","Ah","Toor","Neh"][   "Tah","Gron","Viing","Shul","Viir"]]
```

However, when I run it, I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Is there a way around this/can it be done in a 2d array

Comment: `[..."Dur"]["Mir",...` -> `[..."Dur"] , ["Mir",...`

Comment: Can you show the code you're running that generates that error?

Comment: Oh, sorry I see the issue now. I've provided an answer.

Comment: I agree, but the OP's posted error was due to the lack of commas so that's all there was to really go on for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

wrong list syntax. This works:

```
import random

name = [["Raan","Feim","Od","Yol","Dur"],["Mir","Zii","Ah","Toor","Neh"],["Tah","Gron","Viing","Shul","Viir"]]

print (" ".join([random.choice(nl) for nl in name]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need commas inbetween each list.

```
name = [["Raan","Feim","Od","Yol","Dur"],["Mir","Zii","Ah","Toor","Neh"],[ "Tah","Gron","Viing","Shul","Viir"]]
```

then to get a random name use:

```
from random import randint
print (name[randint(0,2)][randint(0,4)])
```

and you could do this 3 times or however you want the name to come out

**UPDATE**

Something like this is what I'm guessing you want:

```
from random import randint

name = [["Raan","Feim","Od","Yol","Dur"],["Mir","Zii","Ah","Toor","Neh"],[ "Tah","Gron","Viing","Shul","Viir"]]

print(name[randint(0,2)][randint(0,4)] + name[randint(0,2)][randint(0,4)] + name[randint(0,2)][randint(0,4)])
```

Comment: [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) looks like a cleaner and more flexible way to get a random name from the list.

Comment: @Matthias ah yeah, I agree. Been a while since I used Python haha

Answer (score 1):

You need commas between your lists:

```
name = [["Raan","Feim","Od","Yol","Dur"], ["Mir","Zii","Ah","Toor","Neh"], [   "Tah","Gron","Viing","Shul","Viir"]]
```